# How to intercept the fling progress in CardScrollView for GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

When a fling happens in a `CardScrollView`, I see the "zoomed out" view of a long list of cards scrolling by.  This part works fine as in the code below:

```
mCardScrollView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (mSimulatedScrollBar != null)
            mSimulatedScrollBar.setScrollPosition(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

However, the problem is I don't receive any update when this is happening in the `OnItemSelectedListiner` until the fling stops.  The problem this causes is the list scrolls but until it "settles" I don't get any update on the list progress and thus can't respond in the foreground with a progress view.

There are a number of listeners and protected methods for `CardScrollView`, do any provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently aren't any methods or listeners that give you access to the finer scroll details of the view — only events when the user settles on a card or begins scrolling.

If you'd like to see a feature like this, please file a request in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: Done as requested, issue opened: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=385&thanks=385&ts=1390844736